# Mystery space below divs

Tags: html, spacing

I'm struggling to find the reason for a space appearing in a main content div, below the first pair two divs, one floated left, the other floated right. This space only appears below the first two divs, and the layout is repeated down the page. Please see http://gemma-anderson.co.uk/press.html. Any help is much appreciated. Also, if anyone is able to suggest a more elegant way to layout this page, it would be an excellent bonus. Thank you.

Comment: Your page is down. Can you post the code here and/or on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

[MyCodepen](http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/ejvzB/)

Hello, you have two choice for positionning your div

- position
- float

You have the space problem cause your sidebar column and your main content aren't positioned

CSS of my test (with position method) :

```
mainContent{
  position : absolute;
  left:250px;
  top:70px; 
  background:pink;
  width:700px;
}
.logo{
  width:200px;
  height:80px;
  background:green; 
  float:left;
  margin-right:30px}
```